# Find a string using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: string, find, phpmyadmin

i have table in DB = dle_post and a row contains id,full_story i want to check if full_story starts with "1." then list its id but the big problem is there are some spaces in the start of full_story some time 1 some time 2 and some time 3 , how can i list all ids starting with "1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to execute some SQL like this, which you can also do in PHPmyAdmin...

`SELECT id FROM dle_post WHERE LTRIM(full_story) LIKE '1%';`

I think this will work!

Answer (score 0):

Would this query help:

```
$id = fetch id here;
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE id LIKE '%".$id."`%'", $someconnection);
```

YOUR_TABLE -> replace it with your table nime